# Can "defined as" and "referred to as" be used interchangeably?

Tags: phrase-usage

I use "defined as" and "referred to as" interchangeably as follows:

> 1. The line connecting two points A and B is **defined here as** line AB.
> 2. The line connecting two points A and B is **referred here to as** line
>    AB.

However, I am getting worried that the first sentence should be corrected as follows:

> Line AB is **defined here as** the line connecting two points A and B.

Comment: I think this is a question of naming, more than definition, so *referred to*, or *called* or even *named* might fit better. For your last sentence, line AB is the name given to the straight line connecting points A and B. A definition is more like, *A circle is defined as the set of all points equidistant from a single point.*

Comment: What @JackO'Flaherty said. There will be some contexts where the *potential* difference in meaning is inconsequential, but obviously the two verb forms ***to define as*** and ***to refer to as*** have somewhat different meanings, and *that's* what will normally govern your choice of which to use. Are you really ***coining a definition / reminding people of a pre-existing definition***, or are you simply using some particular form of words for convenience?